# Is it possible to run a postbuildevent in an Azure Devops .yaml pipeline build event containing macros such as $(TargetPath)?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, msbuild, yaml, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to automatically rename the .dll resulting from VSBuild so it includes the version number. In order to do this I've tried to create a postbuild event in DevOps.

```
      - task: VSBuild@1
        inputs:
          solution: '$(solution)'
          msbuildArgs: '/p:PostBuildEvent="rename $(TargetPath) $(TargetDir)$(TargetName).$(buildNumber)$(TargetExt)"'
          platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
          configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

This post build event works fine when I put it in Visual Studio and run it locally. However,  I don't want users to be able to change it, so I don't want to define it in Visual Studio but in the pipeline(.yaml) itself. On DevOps I get the following result:

```
PostBuildEvent:
  rename $(TargetPath) $(TargetDir)$(TargetName).20221003.8$(TargetExt)
  The system cannot find the file specified.
##[error]C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5707,5): Error MSB3073: The command "rename $(TargetPath) $(TargetDir)$(TargetName).20221003.8$(TargetExt)" exited with code 1.
```

It seems as though the postbuild event macros, such as $(TargetPath), which are recognized in Visual Studio are not recognized when running the post build event through DevOps pipelines. Is this correct? If so, is there any way around it? I'd prefer not to hardcode anything since I want to reuse the pipeline for multiple repos/solutions with a variable number of projects and project names.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not familiar with Azure DevOps, but just to make sure: are you using a Windows agent for your builds?

Comment: Yes, I am using a Windows agent.

Comment: And does `rename` work for other files?

Comment: $(TargetPath) is a property in MSBuild. My guess is YAML doesn't recognize it and by passing the PostBuildEvent as a property value, MSBuild is not evaluating the string for properties. But you can implement the rename directly in MSBuild.

Comment: @JonathanDodds Yes I think you are right. When I echo $(TargetPath) it outputs the entire path in visual studio but just echo's $(TargetPath) in MSBuild.

How would I go about implementing the rename directly in MSBuild? Don't I need the targetpath from the postbuildevent to know what I have to rename?